# Finding and displaying image src attributes

Tags: jquery

```
> <li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
> <li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
> <li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
> <li><img src="image4.jpg" /></li>
> <li><img src="image5.jpg" /></li>
> <li><img src="image6.jpg" /></li>
> <li><img src="image7.jpg" /></li>
```

I want get the link of img tab in body or a div chill and replace by

|image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg|image5.jpg|image6.jpg|image7.jpg|

Can help me , so hard to do it. I want help  with jquery(),

Thanks

Comment: Please show us more HTML code

Comment: Please give an example of what you would like to have, I don't understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: http://comicvn.net/help.htm. Can u check this link for me? . I am a newbie and dont khow how to reply with full code

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but something along these lines may help:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    files = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    files.push(imgs[i].src);
}
alert(files.join('|'));
```

Comment: Thanks you. . But my problem is :

I have a script work with :

<script type="text/javascript">
var list_images = 'image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg|image5.jpg|image6.jpg|image7.jpg';
var images = list_images.split('|');
</script>



but know in blogger always give more tab in my script

Comment: http://comicvn.net/help.htm. Can u check this link for me? . I am a newbie and dont khow how to reply with full code